How to train a model to detect a specific region (D at top) in an image regardless of varying bottom content?
I want to classify images coming in from a video stream from a moving camera into a few different signs, but the issue is there are 2 types of signs which are really similar:

end_curve (a D at the top, and at the bottom there is an X)
start_curve (a D at the top, and at the bottom a number 1 till 100)

To start with, I have an image for end_curve, but for start_curve I only have a sample image with the number 10 at the bottom.
My Thought Process
I want to finetune an existing model with augmented data for my images, but i cannot make thousands of augmentations for 100 different start_curve signs... so i figured why not make it just learn to tell me whether there is a D at the top or not, then i can perform OCR to check the bottom character/number.
The Issue
I am unsure how to proceed with this or what dataset to use or even augment, if I use X it will learn to detect end_curve, but not start_curve, I assume. I am new to machine learning so I don't know what the next step would be, or if this is the best approach... I appreciate any guidance toward the right direction. I am just seeking help with my method.
